# Cfimage and dynamically naming the "name" portion of the cfimage tag

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a page that displays a series of available items for the public to purchase. Each of these items displays the image for the related product. My `cfimage` code is made to scale-to-fit the stored image.

Normally the displayed results will all show different products and their corresponding images. However, when I use the code all of my products show the same image, instead of showing the images that are linked to each product via a file path stored in the database. Is there a way to set the `"name="myImage"` dynamically so that each image will display and scale properly?

Comment: You need to post some code. FYI: Added the main CF tag for greater visibility.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a race condition so you might just need to scope the name, but like @Leigh says, you need to post some code to say for sure.